# How to convert string to DateTime object with month name, Date and Year flutter?

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart

I have string like "April 20, 2020". I want to convert the string to DateTime().

The problem I am facing is DateTime.parse() is not accepting month name.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Those type of date format is not supported by [DateTime parse](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html). You can use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package to achieve this.

```
var dateString    = 'April 20, 2020';
DateFormat format = new DateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
var formattedDate = format.parse(dateString);
```

Answer (score 8):

Try [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) dart package.

```
DateTime _parseDateStr(String inputString) {
  DateFormat format = DateFormat.yMMMMd();
  return format.parse(inputString);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a list which holds the name of all months then you can perform split operations and find a specific part of string then put all together in DataTime.

The following code will clear your idea.

```
String sdata = 'April 20, 2020';

  List<String> months = [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December'
  ]; 

DateTime _dateTime = DateTime(
        int.parse(sdata.substring(sdata.length - 4, sdata.length)),
        months.indexOf(sdata.split(' ')[0]) + 1,
        int.parse(sdata.substring(sdata.length - 8, sdata.length - 6)));
    print(_dateTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [easy-localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) package for internationalizing your app you can take benefit of that and use methods available

For instance

```
static DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(now) // will give output as March 1, 2023
DateFormat.MMMMd().format(now) // will keep output as March 1
DateFormat.MMMMEd().format(now) // will give output as Wed, March 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String dayNameTR = DateFormat('EEEE', "tr").format(date);
```